# Linux keeping own package manager across the LAN network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-manager

We are using Ubuntu machines for our LAN networks. To install some packages for every machine, we use the Ubuntu package manager `apt`. Let's say about installing `git` for every machine. Instead of installing `git` from the internet for every machine, I want to keep our own package manager in one of our machines as a repository. From that repository, I will install the packages for every other machine. I hope there will be a tool exist for this job in Linux. I want to know what are the tools used for doing this job in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 choices - I recommend #2, #1 will work mostly, #3 for only a couple of machines.

Use a proxy that will cache the `deb` files as they are requested.  First machine gets from internet, others get from cache.  The program `apt-cacher-ng` can do this for you.  https://www.tecmint.com/apt-cache-server-in-ubuntu/

The second option is to set up a webserver and mirror the distribution repository in some fashion. Depending on what your upstream provides (ftp, http, rsync, etc) how you do this is somewhat up in the air. I chose to mirror over http/https using `debmirror` and some shell scripts, and then I serve the directory up with a basic Apache install with a properly set `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directive.

A third option and one I wouldn't really recommend (esp with more than a couple of machines to update) is to share the `/var/cache/apt/archives` directory from the "master source" machine to the others via network (samba/cifs, nfs, sshfs, etc) and then after the first machine updates/installs the others should see the file as already downloaded, assuming they also mount hte share at `/var/cache/apt/archives`.  If you do this though you  have to be careful of using the `apt-get clean` command.